# Reach the value of CheckBoxes in a loop (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen other questions about this, but still can't make it work.

I've got six CheckBoxes and I can reach the value of them doing this...
`Worksheets("MyWorksheet").CheckBox1.Value`

But in my loop, I need to do something like this...
`Worksheets("MyWorksheet").CheckBox(i).Value`
or...

```
Dim Src1 = Worksheets("MyWorksheet").CheckBox1.Value
Dim i
i = 1
MsgBox Src & i
```

I know how to do this in JS, but I'm quite new to VBA and this format.
The CheckBoxes are put directly on the Worksheet and they're ActiveX.

Comment: `Worksheets("MyWorksheet").oleobjects("CheckBox" & i).object.value` should do it

Comment: Or `CallByName(Worksheets("MyWorksheet"), "Checkbox1", VbGet).Value`

Comment: Or `Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Shapes("Check box " & i).DrawingObject.Value`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried Rory's solution and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
Sub test()
    Dim shp
    For Each shp In Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Shapes
        If Left(shp.Name, 9) = "Check Box" Then
            MsgBox shp.Name & " is " & (shp.DrawingObject.Value = 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```